# Custom field default value

Tags: attributes, customer, address

I have defined a `lastname2` attribute for customer and customer_address, it shows up correctly in all forms, but when I'm creating a new address, its does not get 'prefilled' with the customer's value.

Any clues on how to do it?

The definition of my fields:

```
$entityAttributes = array(
        'customer'=>array(
            'lastname2' =>  array(
                'store_label'=>'Apellido Materno',
                'label' => 'Apellido Materno',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type'  => 'varchar',
                //System =  False and visible true = Show in 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'
                'system'=>true,
                'visible'=>true, //Watch out!! Only visible fields get processed by the form controllers!!!
                'user_defined'=>false,
                'used_in_forms' => array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register','customer_account_create'),
                'required' => 0,
                'position' =>69
            ),),
'customer_address'=> array(
            'lastname2' =>  array(
                'store_label'=>'Apellido Materno',
                'label' => 'Apellido Materno',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type'  => 'varchar',
                //System =  False and visible true = Show in 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'
                'system'=>false,
                'visible'=>true, //Watch out!! Only visible fields get processed by the form controllers!!!
                'user_defined'=>false,
                'used_in_forms' => array('customer_account_create','customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address','adminhtml_customer'),
                'required' => 0,
                'position' =>49
            ),
        ),
    );
# Install Attributes
    foreach($entityAttributes as $entity=>$attributes)
    {
        foreach($attributes as $attribute_code=>$definition)
        {
            $installer->addAttribute($entity, $attribute_code,  $definition); 

            /**
            * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Config
            */
            Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute($entity, $attribute_code)
            ->setData('used_in_forms',$definition['used_in_forms'])
            ->save();
        }
    }
```

My config.xml (relevant extracts, the full version is [here](http://pastebin.com/w8Yv0fTi))

```
<global>
<!-- [...] -->
        <fieldsets>
            <!-- @see http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6 -->
            <customer_account>
                <lastname2>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                    <name>1</name>
                    <to_quote>customer_lastname2</to_quote>
                    <to_customer_address>lastname2</to_customer_address>
                    <to_customer_address>customer_lastname2</to_customer_address>
                </lastname2>
            </customer_account>      
            <customer_address>
                <lastname2>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </lastname2>
            </customer_address>
        </fieldsets> 
<!-- [...] -->
</global>
```

**Edit:** Its not the browser's autofill, I want to replicate the behaviour of the firstname and lastname fields, that show the customer's first and lastname (respectively) by default

Comment: You mean there is no autofill for the input field ? What happens to other fields in the same form ?

Comment: I am a bit confused here. When are these fields being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the block `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Edit` this is the block that controls the address editing. In here you will notice the block of code in the `_prepareLayout` function that sets the defaults if the address does not exist, so for new addresses.

```
$this->_address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

// Init address object
if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
    $this->_address->load($id);
    if ($this->_address->getCustomerId() != Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()) {
        $this->_address->setData(array());
    }
}

if (!$this->_address->getId()) {
    $this->_address->setPrefix($this->getCustomer()->getPrefix())
        ->setFirstname($this->getCustomer()->getFirstname())
        ->setMiddlename($this->getCustomer()->getMiddlename())
        ->setLastname($this->getCustomer()->getLastname())
        ->setSuffix($this->getCustomer()->getSuffix());
}
```

Then later on when getting the name html this address object is set against the widget to be used for getting data in the template.

```
public function getNameBlockHtml()
{
    $nameBlock = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('customer/widget_name')
        ->setObject($this->getAddress());

    return $nameBlock->toHtml();
}
```

And then finally these values are being used in the template itself `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml`.

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>
```

So you will need to either hock onto the before html event and make your changes to the address object or rewrite this block. Either way you will also need to change the template to include your new attributes.